# Expandable listview of preferences

Tags: android, preferences

I'm looking for the best way to have an expandable list view that contains preferences
just like in PreferenceActivity, but instead of list that contains categories with each category has its settings, I want the categories to be collapsed, and when tapped it is expanded to show its settings.

Comment: Have you found anything to impelement the feature?

Comment: Nope unfortunately!
Ended up doing it manually in a normal list view.

Comment: thanks for your reply